# Visual Studio 2015, WPF deployment with clickonce. Error ".NET Framework 4.5" required on the user's computer

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2015, .net-4.5, clickonce

i have developed a WPF/MVVM application using Visual Studio 2015. All of WPF application components (ie: model, view, viewmodel) are developed for .NET Framework 4.5. Application is deployed to a web site, and then is installed on users' computers using clickonce installer.
Application works perfectly on our development computers; but when the users download the application, they get this error message:
"Unable to install or run the application. this application requires .NET Framework 4.5 Full or another .NET compatible version"
I included the .NET 4.5 Framework in my deployment package, and I thought it would have been installed all components needed to run the app on the users' computers.
What is wrong in this configuration? please help[image]

Comment: DId you try to uninstall the application and then install it again?

Answer (score 0):

Prerequisites will only be installed when the bootstrapper (i.e. setup.exe) is run. This will not happen automatically. So prerequisites will not be installed when

a) the user only downloads the deployment manifest (*.application)

or

b) prerequisites are added after the installation. Updates will not run the bootstrapper again and thus will not install the new prerequisites.